# Show formula result string location along with the result | Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm brand new here and noticed stack overflow has all the best answers online. So thought I'd try ask a question myself.

This is what I'd like to do:

Current formula to find data to match search term in A5:

`=QUERY({'Jan 2023'!A1:M;'Feb 2023'!A1:M}, "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13 where Col2 = '"&A5&"'",0)`

When the query gets a match to A5 and displays the result:

current result string example:  `13-11-2023, Tigosse, 240`

Desired final result: `13-11-2023, Tigosse, 240, **'Feb 2023'!A25:C25`**

Where **`'Feb 2023'!A25:C25`** is the actual location of the found data

Sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vCdQ5TKfp7dv_qCM-frUGhLWjoXBR2tYpeiDl7vixYU/edit#gid=357764169

TIA

Comment: the shared sheet has *restricted access*

Comment: sorry, try now please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(combined_,reduce(,tocol(P:P,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Σ,indirect(c&"!A1:M"),hstack(Σ,index(c&"!A"&sequence(rows(Σ))&":M"&sequence(rows(Σ)))))))),
     query(combined_, "where Col2 = '"&A5&"'",0))
```

- *the tab names are accommodated in Column_P & the `reduce` part of the formula automatically combines all the tabs data ready for `query`*
- *Column_P is `text-formatted` (where tab names are saved)*

[image]

Comment: amazing. I thought you gave up when you left the sheet. But then I came back to a perfect solution. Well done sir. Thank you very much @rockinfreakshow

Comment: I would like add another search function which will return results for a partial match.

As I understand for VLOOKUP you would use A5&"*"

I tried it with this and it just wouldn't work. Any idea how to modify this wilcard into the formula?

Current search: "where Col2 = '"&A5&"'",0))